# Find doc/docx/txt/rtf/ file containing 12 strings/words only - MAC OS

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, python

This is a strange request and I'm unsure if it's even possible but Google led me here through a not so similar question and so I thought I'd ask.

I basically need to find a text file on my computer that contains 12 strings (characters only), separated by a space - is this possible using terminal or anything?

Comment: For text files it is easy: go to the directory containing the files you want to find and type `find . -iname "*.txt" -exec wc -w "{}" \; | grep "^12 "`. Unfortunately I don't know of a program that will do the same as `wc` for document files: maybe there is a command-line utility somewhere which will extract the text from documents, so that you can pass it to `wc` - perhaps a print option on your word processor?

Comment: Thanks @AFH, rather than naming a directory is it possible to search the entire HDD?

Comment: Yes, either `cd /` before the `find`, or put `/` instead of `.` in the `find` command.

Comment: @Thanks @AFH, I get the message...

`MacBook-Pro:~ Liam$ / find . -iname "*.txt" -exec wc -w "{}" \; | grep "^12 "
-bash: /: is a directory`

Comment: You didn't do what I said: the command is either `cd /` then `find . -iname "*.txt" -exec wc -w "{}" \; | grep "^12 "` or `find / -iname "*.txt" -exec wc -w "{}" \; | grep "^12 "`.